# camera js thumbanil issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using camera js as my main slider, and everything works perfectly fine, except that now that im trying to use thumbnail functions for the better look, it doesn't seem to be working.

http://www.pixedelic.com/plugins/camera/

the camera  js document suggests that all i need to do is to have the option 'thumbnails:true'  and insert `data-src="images/main_image.jpg"`

yet it doesn't seem to work yet.

what did i miss?

here is the code:

```
    <div class="slider">
<div data-thumb="images/main_image.jpg" data-src="images/main_image.jpg"   style="background-size:cover;"></div>
<div data-src="images/main_image.jpg" style="background-size:cover;"></div>
<div data-src="images/main_image.jpg" style="background-size:cover;"></div>
```

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
jQuery('.slider').camera({ //here I declared some settings, the height and the presence of the thumbnails 
pagination: true,
navigation: true,
fx: 'scrollLeft',
height:'960px',
thumbnails: true
});});
```

and the live site : http://www.ike.co.kr/English/main.html

Comment: @raduation I edited it.

Comment: The slider itself seems to work fine.  How should the thumbnails appear?

Comment: If I hover over the navigation dots at the bottom, some thumbnails do pop up - is this the intended behavior?

Comment: @raduation oh  i see. that's how the thumbnails pop up.

Comment: but is there anyway i can make the thumbnails stay on the bottom without me hovering the mouse over the dots? like this? http://www.idangero.us/swiper/demos/23-thumbs-gallery.html

Comment: I don't know that part, you'll have to read the documentation of that particular javascript library.

Comment: okay. thanks for your help and interest though.

Comment: No problem, good luck!